# Using PHP SimpleXML to parse an oBix XML feed?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am rather new to development, but a long time sys-admin. I am trying to retrieve a specific value from the following XML feed. (Its oBix).

```
http://80.68.58.47:900/obix/config/Drivers/NiagaraNetwork/OSS_Tridium_Demo/points/kW_Sys/
```

I am trying to return the "Out" value within the 'Real' element (If element is the right name for it). The value is a number next to val=.

I have spent a fair few hours trying to work out how to isolate the 'val' attribute and return the number but I can't seem to do it. I can isolate the 'real' element but can't go any further in to get the actual number value.

Could someone show me how this is done using PHP SimpleXML so I can try to get my head round it?

This is my code so far:

```
<?php
$url = "http://80.68.58.47:900/obix/config/Drivers/NiagaraNetwork/OSS_Tridium_Demo/points/kW_Sys/";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$elementselection = $xml->real[0];
$outputvalue = $elementselection;
print_r ($outputvalue);
?>
```

Many Thanks!

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the value from the first 'real' element you can use the following:

```
$url = "http://80.68.58.47:900/obix/config/Drivers/NiagaraNetwork/OSS_Tridium_Demo/points/kW_Sys/";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$value = (string) $xml->real[0]['val'];
var_dump($value);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I can see whats going on now. I was trying to drill down too far. I was trying to do "$xml->real[0]->val". Whereas you are going down to real and then selecting an attribute I guess its called by using real[0]['val'].